# MongoDB eval setInterval

Tags: mongodb, eval

I am updating over 1 million of records using eval and it is doing it on about 1000 documents/second. The problem is that while it is updating, I cannot make any more queries so the website is completely not responding to queries.
So I thought I could do it with timeouts, but i am getting error that setTimeout is not defined. How such update operations are usually done ?

EDIT:
I have collection "players" which holds football players information, skills etc. Every day at let's say 12:00 AM I want to simulate players' training. Each player has set his current training. During the training, I want to increase player skill field value by some integer, depending on which training is set. So I need to update every document in collection, currently there are ~1.3 Mln of documents, but it can grow up to ~2 million of documents.
Basically, in a few words, I make football team management game and I need to simulate players' training. But I don't care if training would take even 1-2 hours, it is okay, but I just need that it won't kill server, so it would be done like a "background process"

Comment: `setTimeout` is a browser/NodeJS API and not part of JavaScript. Are you doing `db.eval?` That takes a lock on all JavaScript by default unless you pass a `nolock`.

Comment: Yes, i am doing db.eval and i set nolock:true, but million update operations at once make server unresponsive until they are finished. How is it usually done with updating big amount of data?

Comment: Can you perform the operation in chunks?

Comment: I edited my question with more details, do you think using chunks would be okay for this case?

Comment: Chunks should help. But you're still hammering at the server by changing so many documents. Is there a mathematical way of computing the values such that you don't actually need to make the changes to the documents? Or, could you delay the work until the next time the "player" is accessed? (I'm trying to think of ways you could delay the work as long as possible).

Comment: Thanks for your help. I don't think I can do anything without changing documents, because I want to create player development on daily basis and you can change training style every day. For example imagine you are some sports player, you have your skill levels and each day you can train 1 skill, but one day you train one type of skill, second day other and so on. I think i need to save every details to database. And of delaying: what if nobody access player the whole day, then it won't make training so i don't think it suits me unless you know some way

Comment: If you knew the player wasn't accessed for 3 days, can't you at the point of access fix their stats?

Comment: Well not really, because every day there are also matches simulation, where I need up-to-date player stats, so it needs to be updated on daily basis. Is there any solution to update ~1 millions documents? Time taken is not very important, as I said it could take 1-2 hours or even more, but the problem is that meanwhile mongodb is  working with these queries, it seems to block all other queries, and  I cannot access my website via browser, because it is not responding, so I need to run it like "background process" where it wouldn't interfere with browser queries

Comment: Consider alternate schemas (to reduce doc size), chunks ..., remove `eval`. I don't have any other ideas. Your code is touching a LOT of documents, which keeps MongoDB blocked essentially, constantly.